# Inform users when the document is modified in PhpStorm

Tags: netbeans, phpstorm, php-ide

Is there a way to show the title in bold or show an asterisk* in the title of a modified document in PhpStorm?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisk indeed:

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Editor Tabs | Mark modified tabs with asterisk`

**P.S.**
Settings screen has very nice **search functionality** (input box in top left corner) -- you should definitely try it next time -- very handy tool.

[image]